# Button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How do I add a button to navigation bar that appears only in a particular view controller? And also how to add different buttons to different view controller that is embedded in navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add buttons to navigation bar, rather you could add bar button items. If you want you can customise bar button item to meet your requirements like setting a custom image as suggested by @Pushpendra.

Programatically:
Your View Controller is responsible for providing bar button item(s) for it's navigation bar. Create bar button items inside each of your view controller's viewDidLoad() or in init() if you have overridden it.

Storyboards:
It's pretty handy to drag n drop bar button items from storyboard editor and have the outlets setup so that you can change the behaviour later.

If you are precisely looking to control the behaviour, then you can add or remove a bar button as and when needed depending on your conditional requirements.

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// Assuming this view controller presented/pushed with navigation controller
        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(FooViewController.buttonItemAction(sender:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem
    }

    @IBAction func buttonItemAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem)    {
        /// some action
    }
}


class BarViewController: UIViewController {
    var buttonItem: UIBarButtonItem?
    var showButtonItem = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// Assuming this view controller presented/pushed with navigation controller
        buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: self, action: #selector(BarViewController.buttonItemAction(sender:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem
    }

    @IBAction func buttonItemAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem)    {
        /// some action
    }

    @IBAction func toggleButtonItem(sender: UIButton)   {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = (self.showButtonItem == true) ? self.buttonItem : nil
    }
}
```

If this is what you are not looking for then update your question along with the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
 extension UIViewController {
func addButton(img:String){
    let imgIcon = UIImage(named: img)

 let btn = UIBarButtonItem(image: imgIcon, style: .plain, target: 
  self, action: #selector(self.btnAction))
   // if you want  to set right button then add right bar button item
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn
  }

   func btnAction(){
   }

func removeButton() {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

}

      }
```

when you want to add button
  in viewDidLoad :-

```
  self.addButton(img:"imageName")
```

also if you want to perform separate action on all view controller then 
  call this on controller

```
     override func btnAction() {
      }
```

to remove :-

```
   self.removeButton()
```

if you want to add different button on different controller add the button in **viewDidLoad** and remove in **viewWillDisappear**

Comment: what about `different buttons to different view controller`

Comment: you can remove button when view disappear and again add when you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a bar button item in your navigation bar for the specific view controller in your storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is

Create Viewcontroller inherit from UIViewController or UITableViewController and write a method for setupNavigationButton or buttonText or

(Better to add an action method on a super controller also)

eg:

```
-(void) setupNavigationButton {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"button1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonActin:)];
}
```

and call this method on `viewDidLoad` on the created controller

Next when you create your own controller add this viewcontroler as your parent view controller. So it will automatically add that view.

(You want to write an action on your controller)

Using above method, it saves only one line. But you can save more lines. Let's assume you want to change only text and action on that button.

If it is only you need to change text, write a method to return button text

(Following line for your baseviewcontroller)

```
-(NSString *) rightButtonText {
  return @"";
}
```

and add following codes for baseviewcontroller

```
-(void)setNavigationControler {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[self rightButtonText] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonActin:)];
}
```

and call it on baseviewcontroller

Now your every view controller, you need to override rightButtonText and create selector method and do that action.

Assume you don't need to add that button for some viewcontroler. Then you have a few options

1) Remove baseviewcotroler inheritance from your viewcontroller 
2) After call supper viewDidload add following code

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
```

3) Override setNavigationControler method on your controller with the blank method body.

```
-(void)setNavigationControler {}
```